# NSMutableAttributedString not appending?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to append two NSAttributedString's with the following values and I get the first `NSAttributedString` but not the second. The label is inside a `UITableView`. I have no idea what is causing this problem.

```m
NSMutableAttributedString ms = new NSMutableAttributedString();
NSAttributedString attributedString = new NSAttributedString("Add New Seller ", new UIStringAttributes(){
                    Font = UIFont.FromName("Quicksand-Regular", 17)});
NSAttributedString attributedString1 = new NSAttributedString("+", new UIStringAttributes(){
                    Font = UIFont.FromName("Quicksand-Regular", 17),
                    ForegroundColor = new UIColor(33f, 201f, 130f, 1f)});
ms.Append(attributedString);
ms.Append(attributedString1);
cell.seller.AttributedText = ms;
```

Comment: Note that `UIColor()` should expect values between 0 and 1, so `33/255f`? and so one? Could you print `ms` before/after appending `attributedString1` to check that it's really set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `NSAttributedString` is there appended in the final `NSMutableAttributedString` but you might not see it because it's white. Your issue as @Larme indicated in the comments is with the way you are creating your UIColor.

`UIColor`  accepts `nfloat` values between 0 and 1. When you say `new UIColor(33f, 201f, 130f, 1f)` the resulting Color will be White because it will treat any value over 1.0 as 1.0, hence

`new UIColor(33f, 201f, 130f, 1f)` has the same result as `new UIColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)`.

To fix your code you just need to change the UIColor initialization as

`new UIColor(33f/255, 201f/255, 130f/255, 1f)`

As you see dividing your 3 values of the color (RGB) by 255. The last value represents the alpha.

Hope this helps.-